# Running 'ember server' causes builds to fail with an EEXIST error?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Got this random build error while running `ember server` today. Before you ask, here are my Ember CLI, Node and NPM versions:

```
version: 0.1.15
node: 0.10.33
npm: 2.1.8
```

I created a new Ember project using `ember new [app name]`. Everything worked. I then ran `ember server`, fired up the page on `http://localhost:4200/` and the page showed. I then created a new route called index using `ember generate route index`. As always, Ember CLI created the route, the Handlebars file and a matching test.js. Immediately after this, the running Ember server process threw a build error:

```
file changed templates/index.hbs
EEXIST, file already exists '/Users/Nagarjun/Code/RideBazaar/web-client/tmp/class-tmp_cache_dir-hBTLOW8N.tmp'
Error: EEXIST, file already exists '/Users/Nagarjun/Code/RideBazaar/web-client/tmp/class-tmp_cache_dir-hBTLOW8N.tmp'
    at Object.fs.symlinkSync (fs.js:741:18)
    at symlink (/Users/Nagarjun/Code/RideBazaar/web-client/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/symlink-or-copy/index.js:82:14)
    at Function.symlinkOrCopySync [as sync] (/Users/Nagarjun/Code/RideBazaar/web-client/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/symlink-or-copy/index.js:58:5)
    at /Users/Nagarjun/Code/RideBazaar/web-client/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/broccoli-sourcemap-concat/node_modules/broccoli-caching-writer/index.js:103:21
    at lib$rsvp$$internal$$tryCatch (/Users/Nagarjun/Code/RideBazaar/web-client/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/promise-map-series/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:489:16)
    at lib$rsvp$$internal$$invokeCallback (/Users/Nagarjun/Code/RideBazaar/web-client/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/promise-map-series/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:501:17)
    at lib$rsvp$$internal$$publish (/Users/Nagarjun/Code/RideBazaar/web-client/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/promise-map-series/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:472:11)
    at Object.lib$rsvp$asap$$flush [as _onImmediate] (/Users/Nagarjun/Code/RideBazaar/web-client/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/promise-map-series/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:1290:9)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:345:15)
```

Strangely, when I hit `ctrl c`, stop the server and re-start it, the build is successful. However, when I make a change to the file again, I get the same error. Any clues?

Comment: I get the exact same error, but only since today:
    version: 0.1.15
    node: 0.10.36
    npm: 2.1.8

Comment: @EntspAndi Same here! Never had this issue before.

Comment: Same thing here as well.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Looks like a bug which has been logged against the ember-cli project ([GitHub Issue #3413](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/3413))

I managed to fix it by following the instructions in GitHub Issue #3413. To fix the issue:

1. Add `"rimraf":"2.2.8"` to your `package.json` file (in the `devDependencies` section - below `"glob": "^4.0.5"`)
2. Remove the `node_modules` directory (e.g. on Mac or Linux, execute `rm -rf ./node_modules`)
3. Run `npm install` again

Comment: A cookie for @jmurphyau

Answer (score 0):

Using the following works great for me:

```
"devDependencies": {
  ...
  "glob": "^4.4.2"
},
"dependencies": {
  "rimraf": "2.3.1"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the EExist error when I was trying to `linklocal`. My issue was I was linking two packages with the same name. Check the `package.json` and verify you don't have duplicate `name`